# Count values in previous rows that are greater than current row value

Tags: python, pandas, loops, countif

I want to find the count for the number of previous rows that have the a greater value than the current row in a column and store it in a new column. It would be like a rolling countif that goes back to the beginning of the column. The desired example output below shows the value column given and the count column I want to create.

```
Desired Output:
Value  Count
5      0 
7      0
4      2
12     0
3      4
4      3
1      6
```

I plan on using this code with a large dataframe so the fastest way possible is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do `subtract.outer` from `numpy` , then get lower tri and find the value is less than 0, and sum the value per row

```
a = np.sum(np.tril(np.subtract.outer(df.Value.values,df.Value.values), k=0)<0, axis=1)
# results in array([0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 3, 6])
df['Count'] = a
```

Answer (score 1):

#### IMPORTANT: this only works with pandas < 1.0.0 and the error seems to be a pandas bug. An issue is already created at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35203

We can do this with `expanding` and applying a function which checks for values that are higher than the last element in the expanding array.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame([5,7,4,12,3,4,1], columns=['Value'])
# calculate countif
df['Count'] = df.Value.expanding(1).apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.where(x > x[-1], 1, 0))).astype('int')
```

Input

```
    Value
0   5
1   7
2   4
3   12
4   3
5   4
6   1
```

Output

```
    Value   Count
0   5        0
1   7        0
2   4        2
3   12       0
4   3        4
5   4        3
6   1        6
```

Comment: This code doesnt really work for me, I am getting ```KeyError: -1```. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you created the dataframe exactly as the one displayed under "Input"? Just try to do `df.Value.expanding(1).apply(lambda x: x[0])` which should give you an `pd.Series` where all values are `5`. Does this work?

Comment: Yea x[0] works for me, i get a series with all 5. but x[-1] doesn't. Infact even x[1] doesn't work for me

Comment: so `df.Value.expanding(1).apply(lambda x: x[-1])` doesn't work? Can you index any list with `-1`, e.g. what's your output for `[1,2,3][-1]`? Which python version are you using?

Comment: I updated my answer, can you please copy paste and check whether this works? And what is your result of `[1,2,3][-1]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217571/discussion-between-pythonic833-and-akshay-sehgal).

Answer (score 0):

```
count = []   
for i in range(len(values)):
       count = 0
       for j in values[:i]:
           if values[i] < j: 
              count += 1
       count.append(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below generator will do what you need. You may be able to further optimize this if needed.

```
def generator (data) :
    i=0
    count_dict ={} 
    while i<len(data) :
        m=max(data)
        v=data[i] 
        count_dict[v] =count_dict[v] +1 if v in count_dict else 1
        
        t=sum([(count_dict[j] if j in count_dict else 0) for j in range(v+1,m)])
        i +=1
        yield t

d=[1, 5,7,3,5,8]
foo=generator (d)
result =[b for b in foo] 
print(result)
```